# What is the probability that a stochastic process that arrived at a final point has passed a specific point in the past?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Consider an ensemble of realizations of a stochastic process that all end at the same final point $x_f$ at time $t_f$! How can I calculate the probability distribution of points at which these sample paths were at an eralier time $t_i$ with? 
Or stated differently: How probable is it that the process, which is at $x_f$ at time $t_f$ arrived from an $x_i$ where it was at an earlier time $t_i$?

Please note that this question cannot be answered by using the backward kolmogorov equation.
Also backward stochastic differential equations do not seem to work.

Comment: You need to add more detail. Do all paths start at $(0,0)$? Is this a continuous or discrete process? It sounds like you are modelling some type of Markov process, but I can't tell.

Comment: You are right of course. The process is assumed to be continuous and Markovian and the initial condition is some (quasi)-stationary distribution.

Comment: You might get some insight by modelling this as a Brownian Bridge, then allow for perturbations to the starting position.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I also thought of that. What I basically need, is a Brownian bridge with drift and conditioned on some given initial distribution. In my case I know that there is an external force present. Are you aware of any theory of Brownian bridges in external potentials?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot directly answer your question, but [this paper](http://www-f1.ijs.si/~rudi/sola/seminar-stimulak.pdf) seems to discuss the physics of Brownian particles subject to external forcing. Specifically see the Langevin and Fokker-Plank equations.